# Angularjs ng-animate different approaches

Tags: angularjs

I'm following [angular docs about animations](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) and the approach is like that:

html

```
<div ngview class="animate">
```

css

```
.animate.ng-enter{
    ...
}
.animate.ng-leave{
    ...
}
```

But following [`this page`](http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/tutorial/how-to-make-animations-with-angularjs), the aproach for the same case is something like that:

html

```
<div ngview ng-animate="'animate'">
```

css

```
.animate-enter{
    ...
}
.animate-leave{
    ...
}
```

I would to know the difference about these two approaches, about "best practice", performance and everything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand the second page you have listed is just a wrapper for ngAnimation into a directive. I am not even sure if this is official and if is kept up to date with latest angular releases (especially 1.2).

> Update: ngAnimate reading through the page on yearofmoo I found this that I think answers your question:
>
> *> One of the major reasons why the **ngAnimate directive** was removed was
>   because it was **difficult to integrate 3rd-party CSS animation**
>   libraries into your code. A good example is with the animate.css
>   library, which, to make it work with ngAnimate, you would have to
>   hardcode the combination of CSS classes into the ngAnimate attribute
>   for each event that takes place. This would be much easier with a
>   driver or module that you load into your application and boom things
>   are working.*

I think you should be more concerned on where you would like to write your animations (eg CSS3 vs JS) and go with the mainstream way.

You can find a good up to date guide [on yearofmoo](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html#how-to-make-animations-in-angularjs) explaining the different approaches.

You can also watch egghead.io [lessons 48-50](https://egghead.io/lessons)

Answer (score 0):

Using the directive `ng-animate` is deprecated: the best practice is that all animations are done by adding classes to elements, as in your first example and link to the Angular docs. A fairly comprehensive guide is available at [Year of Moo](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html).

One point to make is that you can still use this to use custom animations defined in javascript. See the [Year of Moo](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html) article for more information, but they start off as:

```
myApp.animation('.animate',....
```

This would be used in cases where you need to support older IE (that doesn't support various CSS transitions/animations), you might want to use a transition from an existing Javascript library, or you might have something very simple Javascript behaviour that still should be treated like an animation (say, adding a class for a few seconds, and then removing it). It's actually a fairly powerful method that allows you to (ab)use Javascript for visual niceties, but keeps it extremely separate from any other logic.

Answer (score 0):

There are three approaches to create animation, css transition, keyframe and JS animation. each has their own pros and cons. You can read this nice article for a comprehensive understandings.

Remastered Animation in AngularJS 1.2 - yearofmoo.com : http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html